# How to inline index on multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, activerecord

This migration works

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.references :user,      null: false
      t.string     :title,     null: false
      t.string     :permalink, null: false
      t.index [:user_id, :permalink], unique: true
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a way to inline index on multiple columns? I tried doing the following but it didn't work

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.references :user,       null: false
      t.string     :title,      null: false
      t.string     :permalink,  null: false, index: {[:user_id, :permalink], unique: true}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you see the method definition for [`column`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column), you'll see that to add an index you must supply the `index` option with a Hash value, and it uses `index` to create the index, but `index` uses `add_index` under the hood, which expects an array of columns in order to create the index and build its name, so you're not able to add those columns if what's being expected is a Hash. It seems what you want is not possible to accomplish, I hope to be wrong.

Comment: @SebastianPalma as column is a method to create a single column it seems really out of scope for it to create multi-column indexes.